# How to extract my list from relation [Prolog]

Tags: prolog

I currently have a relation defined as:

```
relation2(relation(['Course', 'Prof', 'Local'], 
               [['COMP232', 'Tim W.', 'H6010'], 
               ['COMP248', 'Louise L.', 'H5605'], 
               ['COMP348', 'Mohamed T.', 'H7610']])).
```

I also have a function :

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|Rest]) :- member(X, Rest).
```

How would I be able to use the list in relation 2 in member function.So, using list:

```
[['Course', 'Prof', 'Local'], [...] ]
```

My objective is to use the list within the relation and verify if the first element in the list(lets name it header = ['Course', 'Prof', 'Local']) is a member of this list. So,

```
?- member('Name', [header]).
```

Would return true.

Edit:

I seem to be able to get my header with,

```
?- relation2(relation(X,_)).
X = ['Course', 'Prof', 'Local'].
```

But if I use

```
?- member('Course',relation2(relation(X,_))).
false.
```

Why??

Comment: Why such a contrived representation? Why not simply use a list of facts? You can always collect relevant facts in a list if necessary by using standard built-in predicates such as `findall/3`.

Comment: The relation concept is imposed on me, no choice but to use it :P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last query, `?- member('Course',relation2(relation(X,_)))` isn't succeeding because the second argument of member is a predicate rather than a list.  To get a clear understanding of what's going on, you can write a predicate in your file like this:

```
test('Course', relation2(relation(X,_)).
```

and then query `test/2` with free variables, `?- test(X,Y)`, and observe the values of `X` and `Y`. That's those values are exactly what `member/2` is getting, but it is only defined to tell us things about lists.

In order to pass the list in the first argument of `relation/2` to `member/2`, you have to first instantiate `X` by calling the predicate and then call `member/2` with the instantiated `X` as an argument:

```
?- relation2(relation(X,_)), member('Course', X).
```

Note that the second argument of `relation/2` is a list of lists, so in order to check for members therein, you'll have to use a list as your first argument of `member/2`, e.g.,

```
?- relation2(relation(_,X)), member([CourseName, _,_], X).
```

will be true if CourseName matches the first element of the lists.